# How to loop through one column in Excel using VBA until an empty cell and replace a part of that cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a column in excel that I import from a program and it always imports it in this format if these bars represent the cells, |  | with trailing spaces and <> to represent a negative numbers.  The positive numbers come out like this, |  $758.92| also with trailing spaces.  The number format is Currency and I want to be able to sum these numbers and not have to go down the column of 100 or 200 cells and change all of them.
 I started a macro that I want to iterate over each cell and remove the trailing spaces and replace the <> with () to indicate a negative number and just remove the trailing spaces for the positive numbers.

```
Sub Macro1()
        Dim i As Integer, d As Integer
        i = 13
        Do Until .Cells(4, i).Value = ""
            For d = 4 To 100  *I want the loop to stop at the first empty cell.*
                Cells(d, i) = Trim(Cells(d, i))
                Cells(d, i) *Replace the < at the beginning and end with ()*
            Next d
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: use a do until then as before.

Comment: You don't. That's the single most inefficient way to find the last row in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before initiating that first do loop, you can find the last cell of the column if it will be the same each time:

```
lRow= Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Replace A with column you want
```

This will store the last row, and you can replace d = 4 to 100 with:

```
for d = 4 to lRow
```

Comment: I received an "Expected: end of statement" error when I used the For d = 4 to 1Row statement

Comment: The variable I included was LRow, with a lowercase L. If you were using a 1(one) instead of an L, then that would cause that error.  Make sure the variables match and try again.

Comment: Thank you I got it to work.  Would you also know how to replace < with ( in each cell?

Comment: `Cells(d, i) = Trim(Cells(d, i))
Cells(d, i) = Replace(Cells(d, i), "<", "(")
Cells(d, i) = Replace(Cells(d, i), ">", ")")`

I am guessing this is what you are referring to.  The first line trims (from your code). The second line replaces all < with (. And the third line replaces all > with ).  I wasn't sure exactly which lines were necessary.

Comment: No this helped I added the cells.replace lines but changed them to = replace instead.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you. Mark it as the correct answer if it helped you.